# Why is sin(1/x) not a closed map?

Tags: general-topology, functions

I'm supposed to prove that the following function is not a closed map :

$\begin{array}{rcccl}
f & : & ]0,1] & \rightarrow & [-1,1]\\
& & x & \mapsto & \sin(\frac{1}{x})\\
\end{array}$

Using the relative topology for $]0,1]$ and $[-1,1]$ based on the standard one in $\mathbb{R}$. The problem is, I don't actually see why, because every closed set I've tried so far was sent to another closed set.

I tried using the sequence $\{a_k=\frac{2}{(2k+1)\pi}\}$, since, if you add $\{0\}$, it's a compact space in $\mathbb{R}$, meaning its intersection with $]0,1]$ is also closed in the relative topology, but I don't know if the image of this set is supposed to be $\{1\}$, which is closed, or something else.

Or can I simply say that the image of $\displaystyle{\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} f(a_k)}$ is not in $f(\{a_k\})$, meaning it is not closed, even though that limit doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: any monotonically decreasing sequence converging to 0 will be closed in $]0,1]$ because the only possible limit point is $0$ which is not in the set. So then come up with a sequence that converges to zero such that the values of $\sin (1/x)$ are say, all the rationals in $[-1,1]$. Or just any sequence converging to a point in $[-1,1]$ without ever reaching it.

Comment: So, anything with a $\frac{1}{n}$ form should work ?

Comment: @bertrandrussellsghost No, but you can proceed as follows: let $(q_n)$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $(-1,1)$; for each $n\in \mathbb N$ let $x_n\in (2(n-1)\pi,2n\pi)$ such that $\sin x_n=q_n$; then $\{\frac{1}{x_n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is closed in $(0,1]$ and $\{\sin(1/{\frac{1}{x_n}})\mid n\in\mathbb N\}=\{q_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. This is one possibility this answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is closed in $(0,1]$, but $\{\sin n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: It seems like proving that $\{ \sin n \}_n$ is dense is a bit of overkill for this problem. All you need is that $\sin x$ is a periodic function which continuously takes on values between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree! It was just my spontaneous first thought.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't see how $\{\sin(n)\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not actually equal to $[-1,1]$ ? I will try and see.

Comment: @bertrandrussellsghost It can't be equal because it is countable.

Comment: ... oh boy, yes, of course, I'm way too tired, and we literally just used a similar proof in another class, I'm sorry !